# Output of child parent class program

Tags: c#, oop

Please see a simple program below.

```
public class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base class const");
    }
    public void func()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base class method");
    }
}

public class DClass : Class2
{
    public DClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child class const");
    }
    public void func()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child class method");
    }
}
```

Now in main i am calling

```
Class2 obj2 = new DClass();
obj2.func();
```

What should be the output of this program and why. I don't want to use `new` keyword or Virtual override keywords.

Comment: Why not compile it and give it a try? You already have the code written.

Comment: This should be covered by any decent C# textbook and at least another dozen StackOverflow questions.

Comment: could you explain us your aversion against keywords?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, this function will be called

```
--> public void func()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Child class method-ye nai call ho raha"");
}
```

You ask why, because in the object declaration you explicitly declared that obj2 to be a new class of DClass which is the child of Class2 --> Class2 obj2 = new DClass();

```
obj2.func();
```